# Multiple property type for binding in data grid

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding

I have a Data Grid and such that I want to get data into it for different types of classes. Like according to a specific condition, I would like to bind the Data Grid with Observable collection of type int and in some cases, it would be Observable collection of type string. I want to use MVVM architecture so I don't want to use the code behind file. Is it possible to to define the property of Observable collection as follows :

```
ObservableCollection<object> PropertyName { get; set; }
```

Would it be correct to use this in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a data model, for instance

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then the property would be

```cs
public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

`DataGrid` will automatically generate a column for the each data item property.

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"/>
```

But you can manually create and bind columns to properties in XAML

Don't forget to propertly set the `DataContext` which must be set to ViewModel's instance.